# Trying to create a module for HandDetection uisng mediapipe and openCV but getting an error

Tags: python, windows, opencv, pycharm, mediapipe

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time


class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, model_complexity=1, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackingCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.model_complexity = model_complexity
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackingCon = trackingCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.model_complexity, self.maxHands, self.detectionCon,
                                        self.trackingCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img

    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):

        lmList = []

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if id == 8:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                if id == 12:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                if id == 16:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                if id == 20:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                if id == 4:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

        return lmList


def main():

    ctime = 0
    ptime = 0

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)





    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmList = detector.findposition(img)
        if len(lmList != 0):
            print(lmList[4])

        ctime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (ctime - ptime)
        ptime = ctime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 255), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Getting this error unexpectedly:

> WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
> F20230316 09:19:51.302183  3056 collection.h:55] Failed to get tag
> "C2__PACKET" index 0
> *** Check failure stack trace: *** F20230316 09:19:51.302183  7892 collection.h:55] Failed to get tag "C2__PACKET" index 0
> *** Check failure stack trace: ***

I tried to search for this error but there's no solution,
I downgraded `mediapipe` to `3.8.0`

Comment: Can you add more context to your question. What exactly is your problem? Please check out [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You had the wrong sequence of arguments to `Hands` and two additional typos. This version works in my environment:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time


class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, model_complexity=1, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackingCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.model_complexity = model_complexity
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackingCon = trackingCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.model_complexity, self.detectionCon,
                                        self.trackingCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img

    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):

        lmList = []

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if id == 8:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                if id == 12:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                if id == 16:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                if id == 20:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                if id == 4:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

        return lmList


def main():
    ctime = 0
    ptime = 0

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmList = detector.findPosition(img)
        if len(lmList) != 0:
            print(lmList[4])

        ctime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (ctime - ptime)
        ptime = ctime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 255), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) > 0:
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```